# Gwt and in page hyperlinks (#Chapter3) interfere with history tokens

Tags: html, gwt, anchor

In our gwt app some elements are loaded from a cms and added to page as "HTML"-object. Until now this works fine. But now a larger Html-Page is added that has some anchor elements to jump to different parts of this html document.
This anchors look like that:

```
<a href="#Chapter3</a>
```

The problem is that this interferes with gwt's history tokens. On click on such token will lead the app to `<app address>/#Chapter3` and this is not a valid token - leading to start page.

So how to add such inpage links in a html page?

**Update**
At the end i want that a click on `<a href="#Chapter3</a>` jumps to `<a name="Chapter3</a>` in same document - the normal html-behavior.

Comment: Have you tried using anchors without spaces in them?

Comment: yes - all are without space. "chapter 3" was only an example.

Comment: You may want to update your question then, since anchors can not contain spaces and might give cause to answers that are irrelevant. =)

Comment: What is your desired behaviour when link clicked? I know the link is part of the content you don't control, but depending on what you prefer you could process it to ignore the click, or process it to make a different (valid) thing. Tell us :)

Comment: Are you using Activities and Places design pattern?

Answer (score 1):

Attach a ClickHandler to your HTML widget:

```
myHTMLWidget.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

        // Stop this event
        event.preventDefault();

        Element e = Element.as(event.getNativeEvent().getEventTarget());
        if (e.getAttribute("href").contains("#")) {
            e.scrollIntoView();
        }
    }
});
```

You can have a different scroll behavior, if you want (scroll to the cursor position, for example).

Answer (score -1):

A bit crude, but you could try loading your HTML content in an `iframe` (GWT's [Frame](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/Frame.html)).

Comment: it doesn't work - no effect:
new UiDisplayItem(new Label(title), Frame.wrap((new HTML(content)).getElement()));

Comment: Wrapping your content in an `iframe` won't work as the contents of an `<iframe>` will only be displayed if the browser [won't display an `iframe`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/frames.html#h-16.5). What I meant is setting the frame to load your content from your server using a relative URL. The content would have to be a fully-formed HTML.

Comment: ok thats worth a try but as you mentioned it's crude. but overriding the DefaulClickEvent is at least as crude :-|. and all the mess for an so old html feature.

Answer (score -2):

```
Anchor link=new Anchor("Print",true);
```

Comment: **1st** i can't see how "Creates an anchor for scripting. The anchor's href is set to javascript:;, based on the expectation that listeners will be added to the anchor." (java doc for method you mentioned) could help and **2nd** the content is statically delivered from server and i don't want to manipulate it in any way.